# How to fix error "56949f: value too great for base (error token is "56949f")"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

given code:

```
rosepine=("191724" "1f1d2e" "26233a" "6e6a86" "908caa" "e0def4" "eb6f92" "f6c177" "ebbcba" "31748f" "9ccfd8" "c4a7e7" "21202e" "403d52" "524f67")
rosepinemoon=("232136" "2a273f" "393552" "6e6a86" "908caa" "e0def4" "eb6f92" "f6c177" "ea9a97" "3e8fb0" "9ccfd8" "c4a7e7" "2a283e" "44415a" "56526e")
rosepinedawn=("faf4ed" "fffaf3" "f2e9e1" "9893a5" "797593" "575279" "b4637a" "ea9d34" "d7827e" "286983" "56949f" "907aa9" "f4ede8" "dfdad9" "cecacd")

base=0 
surface=1
overlay=2
muted=3
subtle=4
text=5
love=6
gold=7
rose=8
pine=9
foam=10
iris=11
hltlow=12
hltmed=13
hlthigh=14

#test colours
show_colour() {
    
    perl -e 'foreach $a(@ARGV){print "\e[48:2::".join(":",unpack("C*",pack("H*",$a)))."m \e[49m "};print "\n"' "$@"
}

theme="rosepinedawn" #
basec="text"
outlinec="subtle"
wheelc="foam"
xbc="'#$[$theme[$[$basec]]]'"
xoc="'#$[$theme[$[$outlinec]]]'"
xwc="'#$[$theme[$[$wheelc]]]'"


echo $xwc
```

error comes out as

```
 line 36: 56949f: value too great for base (error token is "56949f")
```

I cant fix the formatting

I expected the output

#56949f

I understand that the base must be forced to 10 but i dont know where to specify

Comment: 10 is the base it's _trying_ to use but it's wrong: `f` isn't a valid digit in base 10. If this is in fact a number, and you do in fact want to force use of a correct base, then this is clearly base-16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$[expression]` syntax is a very old style of arithmetic expression
which is now superseded by `$(( expression ))`. The `expression` is
evaluated as a numeric value then `56949f` will cause an error.
I'm afraid you might be confusing the arithmetic expression with
`indirect variable references`.  Then you may want to say instead:

```
declare -n theme="rosepinedawn"
basec="text"
outlinec="subtle"
wheelc="foam"
xbc="#${theme[${!basec}]}"
xoc="#${theme[${!outlinec}]}"
xwc="#${theme[${!wheelc}]}"

echo "$xbc"
echo "$xoc"
echo "$xwc"
```

Output:

```
#575279
#797593
#56949f
```

Then why the OP's first two assignments `xoc="'#$[$theme[$[$outlinec]]]'"` and
`xwc="'#$[$theme[$[$wheelc]]]'"` look to work?
The `Arithmetic Expansion` section of `bash` manual says:

> $((expression))
> ...
> The expression is treated as if it were within  double  quotes

Let's see how `xoc="'#$[$theme[$[$outlinec]]]'"` is expanded.

```
echo "$theme[$[$outlinec]]"
=> rosepinedawn[5]
```

Then

```
echo "#$(( "$theme[$[$basec]]" ))"      # same as "#$[ $theme[$[$basec]] ]"
=> echo "#$(( rosepinedawn[5] ))"       # same as "#$[ rosepinedawn[5] ]"
=> #575279
```

As we do not have to put `$` in front of the variable name in the arithmetic
expansion, `rosepinedawn[5]` evaluates to `575279`.

**[Edit]**

There are several methods of indirect referencing of variables in bash,
meaning the case that a variable holds the name of another vaiable and
you want to refer to the latter variable using the former variable.

#### **${!name}**

This refers to the variable which name is stored in the variable `$name`.
Example:

```
dog="bow wow"
cat="meow"
for animal in "dog" "cat"; do
    echo "$animal:" "${!animal}"
done
=>
dog: bow wow
cat: meow
```

where the variable `$animal` is assigned to `dog` or `cat` in the loop
and `${!animal}` expands to the values of `$dog` or `$cat`.
Please note the `!` syntax is not applicable for array variables because
the `${!name[@]}` expression is reserved for the different purpose (it expands
to the `keys` of the array).

As a side note, we would use an `associative array` in most cases
instead of the indirect referencing mentioned above:

```
declare -A cry          # create an associative array "cry"
cry["dog"]="bow wow"    # associate "dog" with its cry
cry["cat"]="meow"       # similar as above
for animal in "dog" "cat"; do
    echo "$animal:" "${cry[$animal]}"
done
=>
dog: bow wow
cat: meow
```

#### **declare -n nameref=name**

This is another approach to indirectly refer to the value of the variable
including array variables. In the delcaration above, `nameref`
works as something like an *alias* or a *reference* to `name`.
You can dynamically change the value of `nameref` by using `declare`
to switch the referencing.
Example:

```
declare -a eng=("Sun" "Mon" "Tue" "Wed" "Thu" "Fri" "Sat")
declare -a ger=("So" "Mo" "Di" "Mi" "Do" "Fr" "Sa")

declare -n week="eng"
echo "${week[2]}"       # yields "Tue"

declare -n week="ger"
echo "${week[2]}"       # yields "Di"

# you can also make a loop

for lang in "eng" "ger"; do
    declare -n week="$lang"
    echo "${week[3]}"   # yields "Wed" and "Mi"
done
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked out for the above code and I understand the parts where "[ ]" is superseded by "(( ))" but i do not fully understand the situation. Firstly, how do i use the declared variable (theme in this case) with different values as i need them to be done in a loop? Also, in the first code block you provided, what does ! and the parenthesis mean and change the behaviour?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I did not well explain about the `indirect variable referencing`. I've added some explanations in the `[Edit]` section in my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again. I was only free now to clearly understand what you wrote about indirect referencing. You have been a great help  :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Would you please accept this answer (by clicking the checkmark on the top left of this answer) to close your question? BR.

Comment: Done. My first post so i donno how all this works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thank you too and keep on enjoying coding. If you have any other questions (apart from this topic), please come back and feel free to ask. Good luck!